# How to initialize a typed array with values?

Tags: assemblyscript

Assemblyscript initializes typed arrays with their length, like this:

```
var arr = new Uint8Array(2);
```

Suppose I want to seed this array with some values, like [12, -47, 91], how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.
One must use `StaticArray` like this:

```
var arr:StaticArray<i8> = [12, -47, 91];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach if you need typed array instead `StaticArray`

```
const arr = new Uint8Array(3);
arr.set([12, -47, 91]);
```